# Add values from existing object to JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, object, jtable

So I have a method retrieving data from a mysql database, and I store it in a 2 dimensional array 'values[i][k]';

Where i represents each individual record, and k presents each value in a record.
How would I add this object to a JTable?

The values would look like this in the table, but I want it to be done automatically rather than me having to write it out manually...

values[0][0],values[0][1],values[0][2], values[0][3];

values[1][0],values[1][1],values[1][2], values[1][3];

values[2][0],values[2][1],values[2][2], values[2][3];

values[3][0],values[3][1],values[3][2], values[3][3];

Keeping in mind, values i and k could be any number, not a fixed value.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I have a method retrieving data from a mysql database

As you have method to retrieve data from database and wants to store it in table you can do like this:

//Global Declaration

```
private Vector<Vector<String>> data; //used for data from database
private Vector<String> header; //used to store data header
```

//Display info to JTable

```
data = get();

//create header for the table
header = new Vector<String>();
header.add("Column1"); 
header.add("Column2");
...
model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
table = new JTable(model);
```

This will help you to get data from database

```
get(){
Vector<Vector<String>> doublevector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Connection conn = dbConnection();//Your Database connection code goes in dbConnection()
PreparedStatement pre1 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Table");

ResultSet rs1 = pre1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next())
{
Vector<String> singlevector = new Vector<String>();
singlevector.add(rs1.getString(1)); 
singlevector.add(rs1.getString(2)); 
....
doublevector.add(singlevector);

}

return doublevector;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for you to create a 2 dimensional array to hold the data temporarily.

You can use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` as you read each row from the ResultSet.